# line in the center of the head using facebuilder

Tags: modeling, mesh, scripting, modifiers, objects

[image]

Hello. I made this head using an addon called Face Builder.
Is there any way to get rid of this line appearing above my head?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: maybe try to paint with the Clone brush? (Ctrl left click to sample an area)